# My core locator won't work

Tags: ios, swift, authorization, core-location, cllocationmanager

For the past 2 hours I've been trying figure out why the core locator won't find my devices location.
 The facts are:
- It doesn't work on the emulator or my iPhone
- I can accept the application to access my location in app but after that nothing happens
- I'm using Swift and using Xcode 6.4
- I've input both NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription into my info.plist

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class satelliteViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapTypeTitle: UIButton!

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager!.delegate = self
        locationManager!.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation() 
    }

    @IBAction func changeMapType(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Unimportant     
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement the delegate functions such as `didUpdateLocation` ?

Comment: I've added the didUpdateLocation, didFailWithError and didChangeAuthorizationStatus functions before but It didn't seem to do anything

Comment: Can you show us the code of these function ?

Comment: I got it working, thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

hey just simply enable the location services of your app by entering inside > settings > your App > Location > **Always or while using app** ..have a nice day

Comment: That's not it unfortuantly. It already sets it to 'While using app' after I accept the application to access my location

Comment: whether you are forgetting to import one of framework like **core location** or just try by deleting app from your phone and reinstall it again it will ask for your permission to allow location services along with your keys message which you have given in plist file ..

Answer (score -1):

In your `info.plist`, add two properties : `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` like,

[image]

And then check that if ios version is 8.0 or greater then,

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
    {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

This is in objective c, convert in swift!!

And make sure your location service is on for your app from settings app.

Make sure you are setting proper delegates and implements necessary methods.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: He said that he already added the two properties to his `Info.plist`.

Comment: then he need to add code also which i mentioned in answer. I am giving fully scenario required for location update.

Comment: she**
Thanks for your assistance, I ended up answering the question :)

Comment: @Demi : you're welcome.. :) If you think this is helpful then accept the answer so other people with similar issue can use it. :)